# ESXI 4.1 - tw_cli to manage 3ware 9650 raid card

Tags: vmware-esxi, 3ware

Is there some way in the esxi cli to enable tw_cli to manage the arrays on the 9650se raid card? The goal is to manage the drives (checking array status, building arrays, etc.) without shutting down ESXi.

Answer (score 0):

Try here:  https://www.3ware.com/3warekb/article.aspx?id=15548

They mention that their own version of tw_cli is required.  Not sure if the 4.0 will work with 4.1 or not, but I don't see anything specific to 4.1 itself.